# Get last non-NaN value for each month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame of the form

```
eqt_code    ACA_FP  AC_FP  AI_FP
BDATE                           
2015-01-01     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-02     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-05       1    NaN    NaN
2015-01-06     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-07     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-08     NaN    0.2    NaN
2015-01-09     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-12       5    NaN    NaN
2015-01-13     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-14     NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-01-15     NaN    NaN    NaN
```

And I would like, for each month, to get the last non-NaN value of each column (NaN if there is no valid value). Hence resulting in something like

```
eqt_code    ACA_FP  AC_FP  AI_FP
BDATE                           
2015-01-31       5    0.2    NaN
2015-02-28      10      1      3
2015-03-31     NaN    NaN      3
2015-04-30      10      1      3
```

I had two ideas to perform this:

- Do a `ffill` with a limit that goes to the end of the month. Something like `df.ffill(<add good thing here>).resample('M').last()`.
- Use `last_valid_index` with `resample('M')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `resample`

```
df.resample('M').last()
Out[82]: 
            ACA_FP  AC_FP  AI_FP
eqt_code                        
2015-01-31     1.0    0.2    NaN
```

Comment: Think you need `last`!

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` and `last`:

```
# Do this if the index isn't a DatetimeIndex.
# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)).last()

            ACA_FP  AC_FP  AI_FP
BDATE                           
2015-01-31     5.0    0.2    NaN
...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.dropna(how='all')` will remove each row where all the values are `NaN`, and will get you most of the way there.